# Get Full path name from Uri in android

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

How do I get Full path from a Uri,
Just like /Removable/MicroSD/

I use the below code to let the user pick the SD card on Lollipop to get the Write access to the SD card.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);
```

Created a method onActivityResult to process the result with below code

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
    WriteDebugData(pickedDir.getName());
}
```

However it returns directory as **MicroSD** , what I require is the full path name **/Removable/MicroSD/**

PS: I also want all the links referring to the Uri, for Ex
**/Removable/MicroSD/** and **/Storage/MicroSD/** both paths refer to External MicroSD card, how do I get them all?

Comment: `/Removable/MicroSD/` Can you please telll in which device that would be a correct file path?

Comment: @greenapps on Asus ZF5 its symlink to /storage/MicroSD/

Comment: A symlink? Cannot believe that such things are used by document tree. Having that uri of a directory you can easily list all files in it. Just follow the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get Full path from a Uri, Just like /Removable/MicroSD/

You don't.

First, there is no requirement that the `Uri` actually point to physical storage at all. For example, cloud services accessed through `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` (e.g., Google Drive, Dropbox) might well return you a `Uri` that, internally, it uses as a lookup key into a database containing a local cache of the list of available documents.

Second, there is no requirement that the `Uri`, even if it points to physical storage, be a place on physical storage that you can access. In particular, on any device that has the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`), you do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Or, for cloud services, the physical storage may be [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), private for their apps.

Third, there is no requirement that the `Uri`, even if it points to physical storage that you could access, actually bake that location data into the `Uri` itself. The `Uri` could be `content://some.authority.string/asdfklasj2348dfljaslkdfj`. In fact, I would counsel any developer creating a `ContentProvider`, particularly ones in support of the Storage Access Framework, to ensure that the `Uri` values are opaque as possible.

IOW, [a `Uri` is not a reference to a local file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html), any more than a URL to a Web server is a reference to a local file.

Comment: Lets say I'm creating file explorer, the user want's to create new file in SD Card under /Removable/MicroSD/Documents/, the user grants access to root of SD Card. I need to know the SD card directory to create file under Documents directory. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @RamKumar: "the user grants access to root of SD Card" -- the user can grant you rights through the Storage Access Framework. You can continue using that access through the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`). If granting you access to something in the Storage Access Framework changes the underlying Linux access rules, that's a security flaw that would need to be fixed. "How do I achieve this?" -- you build your own custom ROM and distribute your file explorer on it. Or, you get a job with a device manufacturer, and arrange for private access to removable storage.